# Magento paypal and authorize.net duplicate order issue

Tags: magento, duplicates

When some customer order items using paypal express or authorize.net, they got "transaction decline" error. But payment and order processed. 
So the customer order again.
But payment 2 times.

The "transaction decline" error occurred but the order is processed.

How can I do this?

My magento version is 1.4.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Magento 1.4 had some issues with duplicate orders. [See here](https://www.google.com.au/search?ix=acb&ie=UTF-8&q=Magento%201.4%20duplicate%20orders)

Upgrading to the current version should fix your problem.

[Download latest version](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download)

[How to upgrade Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/upgrading_magento)